# Switch -Regex in Powershell

Tags: .net, vb.net, powershell, powershell-2.0

```
$source |% {
switch -regex ($_){
'\<'+$primaryKey+'\>(.+)\</'+$primaryKey+'\>' { 
$primaryKeyValue = $matches[1]; continue; }

}
```

I want to use dynamic key value with switch-regex, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a string which automatically expands variables:

```
switch -regex (...) {
    "<$primaryKey>(.+)</$primaryKey>" { ... }
}
```

instead of piecing everything together with string concatenation (which is rather ugly). `switch -RegEx` expects a literal string. Furthermore, there is no need to escape `<` and `>` in a regular expression, as those aren't metacharacters.

If you desperately need an expression which generates a string (such as your string concatenation, for whichever reason), then you can put parentheses around it:

```
switch -regex (...) {
    ('<'+$primaryKey+'>(.+)</'+$primaryKey+'>') { ... }
    ('<{0}>(.+)</{0}>' -f $primaryKey) { ... } # thanks, stej :-)
}
```

You can also use expressions that explicitly do a regex match with braces; see `help about_Switch`.

Comment: In this case I would use `('<{0}>(.+)</{0}>' -f $primaryKey)` instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: @stej: Thanks, that's also a nice variant; I added it in :-)

Comment: @stej: I consider the inlined variables more readable in this case ... but my stance on code readability changes from time to time too :-)